# Why is 275481/69/100089 the max date "new Date()" will parse?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Date object susceptible to the Y2038 problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608108/is-javascripts-date-object-susceptible-to-the-y2038-problem)

So after stumbling across [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462687/javascript-equivalent-to-nets-datetime-parse) w/ jquery.validate's date validator, I was testing the upper bounds of JavaScript's new Data() parser.

Oddly, this works:

```
var d = new Date("275481/69/100089")
// d = Date {Fri Sep 12 275760 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
```

However, all of these fail:

```
var d = new Date("275481/69/100090")
var d = new Date("275481/70/100089")
var d = new Date("275482/69/100089")
```

Have I just discovered the date the world will end?

Comment: You know where the name of this site comes from, right? :)

Comment: It's the end of the Aztec calendar. >.>

Comment: Every single one of those gives an `Invalid Date` for me in Chrome... And just looking at them, they look pretty invalid. So uh, what are we yelling on about?

Comment: @AlexWayne: Same for me.  Test harness: http://jsfiddle.net/htt9N/

Comment: @AlexWayne I ran these through Firebug, but that shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Comment: @JeradRose: It appears FF and IE both allow the first date, but Chrome returns "Invalid Date" for all four.  So it does matter, because you are apparently using FF.

Comment: @mellamokb Ok, sounds right. Because your jsfiddle link provides the same results that I posted.

Comment: FYI, Chrome parses for valid month, day, and year values, so `new Date("13/13/2013")` fails, but `new Date("1/1/0100")` does not. Oddly, `new Date("1/1/012")` will return 1/1/2012 in Chrome and 1/1/1912 in IE.